# Excel, MIN for overnight times

Tags: excel-formula

My current data is like so:

[image]

I use the MIN formula to get the minimum of these times. I am measuring a process time, so the time on T is the least, and T+1 is actually greater. How can I alter my MIN formula to account the 11:51 as the min time?

I can use MAX for above problem, but then when times are 3, 4 , 5 AM, it will give me 5 AM when I want MIN throughout.

Comment: Well I can probably use MAX for this example, but still would like to know incase all times are on the same day.

Comment: At what point to you consider a day starting over? Are you days 5pm - 4:59:59pm? If so, you can add 7 hours to each time and then grab the min().

Comment: Days are usually sometime at night till the next morning (ex 20:00 to 08:00), these times are inconsistent, i'll try adding the hours

Comment: Updated question for more clarity. A little bit tricky to follow.

Comment: You say the times to determine a day are inconsistent. How would you determine it though, as a human. How do you know that 11:51:48 PM is before 12:14:07AM.  Me, looking at this data, I would agree with excel. 11:51:48PM is definitely after 12:14:07AM. Would it make sense to say that a workday starts and stops at 12pm (Noon)? Is there another time that better delineates your days? If it's inconsistent, then I don't see anyway to do this, unless you track that day start/stop time for each row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around this is to add the date to the time.  You do not need to display it, but you do need the date as part of the time.  JNevill is all over this without coming right out and saying it.  You can either do as Jnevil suggest and offsetting all your time by an equal amount so it is all in the same day or you have to add +1 to the time when it crosses the midnight threshold.  Adding +1 to your time will tell excel that it is on the following day.

In Excel time is stored as a decimal and days are stored as integers.  So any time with no date attached will go from 0.xxx to 1.xxx when +1 is added.  The cell will still display xxx as time and the 1 does not enter in to the display.  However the 1 will be very important in determining  MIN or MAX because of that integer of 0 or 1 out front.

You will probably need to do this through a helper column.  Without seeing a column of data it is hard to say if you only need to add 1 or if you will need to add 2 or more depending on how many days the data covers

Comment: so days before the midnight, I could add 0 as an offset date,and 1 for those over midnight (1 am, etc).  Am I correct? How should I combine these 0 and 1 with the cell times?

Comment: just add +1 for times after midnight.  you can add +0 if you wish to times before midnight but it is not required.